# Non-defining relative clause

Tags: relative-clauses

Is this a non-defining relative clause?

> Globalization is the driving force behind growth in global trade, **which facilitates exchange of goods among countries.**

If so, can I write:

> Globalization is the driving force behind growth in global trade, **facilitating exchange of goods among countries.**

Comment: Yes and yes. But the first one has an ambiguity (_which_ could refer to either _globalization_ or _global trade_) that the second one avoids.

Comment: Why would you, though? How is 'Globalization is the driving force behind growth in global trade' not tautological repetition? 'Globalization is behind global trade…'?

Comment: It's not clearl to me if " which facilitates exchange of goods among countries" is meant to modify globalization, growth, or global trade.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because both examples are ambiguous and both require re-writing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There is only one "global trade," which is uncountable in any event, so the relative clause cannot serve to pick out one *specific* global trade. So this can indeed be replaced with a participle, though it may be unclear whether that participle is modifying "global trade" or the sentence as a whole.

Comment: Non-defining relatives are supplements, not integrated into clause structure and hence not modifiers. I'd say it refers to the entire preceding clause.